# TypeError: While storing the bytes to mongo db using python

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb

I am trying to write a big program where i do server client communication and everything works but when i am trying to store the client data into Mongodb which is connected at server-side, i am getting error as follows.

Error:

```
TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

At client side my data type shows as string and at server side when i printed the type it says its bytes. But why bytes are not storing in the database. Please post your ideas, I am also new to python. 
Thanks

ServerSide:

```
import re
#getting ip address from machine and bd it to the client
class C():



          if __name__ == "__main__":
              ethernet_card = "wlp3s0"
              ip = ip1(ethernet_card)
          self.sock.bind((ip,4242))
          self.clients_list = []



    def talkToClient(self, ip):
            self.sock.sendto("ok".encode('utf-8'), ip)

    def listen_clients(self):
        #listen to multiple clients
            def parse(msg):
                uri = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
                client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
                database = client['orchtrail']
                collection = database['testData']
                result = database.testData.insert_many(msg)
                testData = collection.find({})
                for test in testData:
                    print(test)
                result.inserted_id
            while True:
                msg, client = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                print(type(msg))
                print(msg)
                parse(msg)

                print('connected with : ' + client[0]+ ':' + str(client[1]))
                t = threading.Thread(target= self.talkToClient,args=(client,))
                t.start()

if __name__=='__main__':
    C= C()
    C.broad(msg="")
    C.listen_clients()
```

client side

```
temperature=""
hum=""
json=json.dumps({"temp"=temperature,"hum":hum})
msg=json
self.sock.sendto(msg.encode(),address)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting data at:

```
result = database.testData.insert_many(msg)
```

The error shows that `msg` should be `dict`, but you wrote that you checked and it is of type `byte`.

So your problem is: how to convert a `json` stored as `bytes` into a `dict`?

You can do the following:

```
import pickle
import json

msg_as_dict = json.loads(pickle.loads(msg))

# check the type of msg_as_dict
print(type(msg_as_dict)) # should be <class 'dict'>
```

then save to your Mongo DB:

```
result = database.testData.insert_many(msg_as_dict )
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks btw i just got it working. Ill post my answer too.

Comment: @keerthana Great to hear! Welcome to the site by the way. Once you feel like your question has been answered, don't forget to accept the answer ;)